# How to put a countdown trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just got into Game Dev and I need my script to enable when my player steps a cube trigger, but I don't know how.

This is the Script that I typed and I can't figure out if I should erase the `Void Start` or not?

```
public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public bool timerIsRunning;

    public Text timeText;

    public float timeRemaining = 10;

    private void Start()
    {
        timerIsRunning = true;
    }

    void Update(){
        if (timerIsRunning)
        {
            if (timeRemaining > 0)
            {
                timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
                DisplayTime(timeRemaining);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Time has run out!");
                timeRemaining = 0;
                timerIsRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay){
        timeToDisplay += 1;

        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60); 
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

        timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you would want to replace `Start` and the `Update` by a simple `IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){  }` .. also I would make it a `private bool` so you can't by accident already enable it via the Inspector

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make good use of a trigger collider. To do that, you need to add a collider of your choice to your zone and set it as a trigger. Be sure to have a collider and a rigidbody on your player.

Then in your script you can use the function OnTriggerEnter who will be called when an object enter in your zone defined by your trigger collider.

For your countdown method, you can make good use of a couroutine. It will look like this :

```
IEnumerator DisplayTime() {
    timeIsRunning = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < timeRemaining; i++) {
        // your code to change the text
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
    timeIsRunning = false;
}

private void OnColliderEnter(Collider other) {
    if(!timeIsRunning) {
        StartCouroutine(DisplayTime());
    }
}
```

What this code does is when an object enter in the trigger, it starts a routine who will update the time displayed each second until the countdown is finished.

With that you won't need your Start and your Update methods anymore.

If you want more informations on trigger collider : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html

If you want more informations on couroutines : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

If you want more informations on the method OnTriggerEnter : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html